# Why parenthesis or brace initialization doesn't work to specify default parameter of a function

Tags: c++

The parenthesis or brace initialization doesn't work to specify **default parameter** of a function. We are forced to use equal (`=`) sign to specify default parameter.  I'm wondering what could be the reason?

```
using namespace std;

float PerimeterCircle(float radius, float PI = 3.14f)    //works fine
//float PerimeterCircle(float radius, float PI{3.14f})   //doesn't work. compilation error
//float PerimeterCircle(float radius, float PI(3.14f))   //doesn't work. compilation error
{
    return PI * radius * 2;
}

int main() 
{
    float r{ 2.0f };

    cout << "Perimeter of circle with radius " << r << "m = " << PerimeterCircle(r) << endl;
    cout << "Precise perimeter of circle with radius " << r << "m = " << PerimeterCircle(r, 3.1415f) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looking very briefly at the dup, tl;dr; that's just the way the language works.  Who ever said C++ was easy?

Comment: The grammar of the language **only** allows `=` to specify default parameter value.  The reason is: that is how the language is designed.  When I posed a similar question about C++ language design to Bjarne Stroustrup, he replied to me "If you don't like it [C++], feel free to create your own programming language.  I did."  (I tried to make my own programming language.  Turns out, that's hard.  But I got very lucky, because Walter Bright made the almost exact language I was trying to create, **D** programming language.)

Comment: @Eljay Excellent comeback from Bjarne there (you name dropper you ), but I think that's what he usually says when people complain about some aspect of the way the language works.  I've certainly heard it before somewhere.

Comment: Thanks all. Though this question is linked with a `duplicate` question, whose answer covers this question still I prefer to keep this question as it provides flexibility in searching using names of different initialisation options.

Comment: @MKR That's fine, it may well stick around.